# Ссылка в JS-скрипте replace

Tags: preg_replace, javascript, замена, php, replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function repl(a) {
    var b = {
        "доставка": "shop_content.php?coID=1",
        "гарантия": "shop_content.php?coID=2",
        "оплата": "shop_content.php?coID=3",
        "как оформить": "shop_content.php?coID=4"
    };
    for (var c in b) {        
        var d = RegExp(c, "gim");
        a = a.replace(d, '<a href="'+b[c]+'">'+ c + '</a>');
    }
    return a;
}

var a = document.getElementByClass("myurls");
a.innerHTML = repl(a.innerHTML);
</script>
```

потом вот:

```
<div class="myurls">
    <p>
        доставка точно в срок!<br />
        гарантия от поставщика!<br />
        оплата любым удобным способом!<br />
        как оформить

    </p>
</div>
```

и нифига...

Comment: чего-то я не помню чтобы HTMLElement имел свойство data, что это такое по вашему ? (`all_elements[i].childNodes[j].data`)

Answer (score 1):

Собрал вам рабочий пример на [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/893Z7/1/)

**javascript**

```
function repl(a) {
    var b = {
        "доставка": "shop_content.php?coID=1",
        "гарантия": "shop_content.php?coID=2",
        "оплата": "shop_content.php?coID=3",
        "как оформить": "shop_content.php?coID=4"
    };
    for (var c in b) {        
        var d = RegExp(c, "gim");
        a = a.replace(d, '<a href="/'+b[c]+'">'+ c + '</a>');
    }
    return a;
}

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

for(i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].innerHTML = repl(a[i].innerHTML);
}
```

**html на входе**

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
        доставка точно в срок!<br />
        гарантия от поставщика!<br />
        оплата любым удобным способом!<br />
        как оформить
    </p>
</div>
```

**html на выходе**

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
        <a href="#link-delivery">доставка</a> точно в срок!<br>
        <a href="#link-warranty">гарантия</a> от поставщика!<br>
        <a href="#link-buy">оплата</a> любым удобным способом!<br>
        <a href="#link-faq">как оформить</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mimino, скрипт работает нормально.  
Даю намек 1: сколько элементов с одинаковым атрибутом ID может быть на странице? И сколько у вас?  
Даю намек 2: вы поставили свою ссылку вместо моего якоря, который был установлен просто для примера?

Comment: @Mimino я вас наверное расстрою и немного испорчу ваш  мир полный автоматики, но все кроссылки в википедии прописаны вручную, примерно так: `[[Википедия]]`, есть конечно и роботы которые ползают по статьям и пытаются слинковать даты и пр. но это скорее исключение.

Comment: @Mimino 1. id в документе должны быть уникальны.

Comment: getElementById("myurls"); а потом использую <div id="myurls">. Это уникальный ID

Comment: Что именно теперь не работает? Вы даже не потрудились заменить список ссылок на свой!

Comment: потрудился. посмотрите, результат я выложил в топике.
Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Есть, и не один. **document.getElementByClass** возвращает не один элемент, как это делает **document.getElementById**, а **список элементов**. Вы же пытаетесь обработать список как один элемент.  
@Mimino , я обновил свой ответ.